# What is the difference between "XXMaxPermSize" and "xmx" in eclipse.ini?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, jvm, jvm-arguments

I'm trying to figure out the difference between the two since my eclipse sometimes experiences a "out of memory" error. I've got a lot of memory at my disposal so I'm trying to figure out which to increase or decrease and what they do to get it working properly. Here are the contents of the file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-clean
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx2000m
```

Comment: permgen space and heapspace

Comment: what's permgen (and how does it relate to eclipse) and how does it differ from heap?

Comment: I believe that the Permgen heap has been removed in Java 8. I would assume that options for it are now deprecated or were removed. Permgen heap is the place where the JVM decided to store everything it though was permanent, class definitions mainly. This caused problems with dynamic loading/unloading of classes because it was never swept for garbage.

Comment: Okay so assuming I have a very large project I should be more worried about MaxPermSize than heap since it's got to store all the data associated with every class for the project?

Comment: The permgen space usually only contains the definitions of classes and some other metadata that usually will not go out of scope. It does not store objects allocated with new. Most of the time you do not have to worry about running out of permgen space unless you plan to "reload" classes at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get an error, you need to read it carefully because often every word matters.  For example, when you get an OOME, you will see some words as a message.  This is important because there is many reasons you can get an OOME and two of the most common ones are;

- a lack of heap spaces (object instances) which is controlled by `-Xmx`
- a lack of perm gen (code) which is controlled by `-XX:MaxPermSpace=`

Note: Java 8 doesn't have a "Perm Gen" it has a "Metaspace" which does the same thing, but works rather differently and I suspect they renamed it to avoid confusion.

There are other reasons for this error such as using too much direct memory, or being unable to create a new thread but these are relatively rare.

If you take away one point for this answer is to read the entire message, not just the error itself, and if you don't know what it means, often Google does ;)

I say this because often a question is posted on StackOverflow regarding an "error occurred" and the first comment is "what error occurred" because as soon at it is posted the problem is obvious (to someone who knows what it means) what the problem is most of the time.  So when you read an error message you need to assume its trying to tell you something, but you don't know what it means *and yes I see new error messages which I don't know what they mean quite often*

Comment: The metaspace is a less permanent permgen space. Stores the same thing with slightly less meta-metadata. One major difference is that the metaspace is managed the same as other heap spaces and can be garbage collected, although it is a lot less frequent.

Comment: @Smith_61 ... and metaspace comes with its own tuning parameters which are specific to how it works.

Comment: What is funny is that the metaspace can also run out of memory in a similar fashion to the permgen space. So I agree that the Metaspace is mostly just a renamed Permgen space.

Answer (score 1):

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=64m
```

> [Size of the Permanent Generation.  [5.0 and newer: 64 bit VMs are scaled 30% larger; 1.4 amd64: 96m; 1.3.1 -client: 32m.]](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

no longer exist in `>= 8` version

```
-Xmxn
```

> Specify the maximum size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool. This value must a multiple of 1024 greater than 2MB. Append the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, or m or M to indicate megabytes. The default value is 64MB. The upper limit for this value will be approximately 4000m on [Solaris 7 and Solaris 8 SPARC platforms and 2000m on Solaris 2.6 and x86 platforms, minus overhead amounts.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out [this](http://indrayanblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/cxv.html) page for further reading, however Jigar Joshi's answer of the diference being between permgen space and heapspace is correct.

A quotation from this page is:

*Suppose one set JVM parameters as*

*-Xms3072M -Xmx3072M -XX:+AggressiveHeap -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M*

*Doubt Is:When we say MaxPermSize = 1024M does it mean that it is taken from
3072M that I set for Xms/Xmx ?*

*Answer is No, PermSize is additional to the -Xmx value set by the user on the JVM options. But MaxPermSize allows for the JVM to be able to grow the PermSize to the amount specified. Initially when the VM is loaded, the MaxPermSize will still be the default value (32mb for -client and 64mb for -server) but will not actually take up that amount until it is needed. On the other hand, if you were to set BOTH PermSize and MaxPermSize to 256mb, you would notice that the overall heap has increased by 256mb additional to the -Xmx setting.**